# Can I change the order of OnCollectionChanged events firing after changes to ObservableCollections from another thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

I have a MVVM application. I have ObservableCollections that hold my models. If OnCollectionChanged is fired and we have "Add" event then I insert the item into my data base.

I have a function that reads data from a file, creates models and adds them to their collection. Because of relations in my database I have to add them in certain order.

Example:

- Post (post id, post number, post town)
- Gender (gender id, gender)
- Person (name, last name, post id, gender id)

So I would first make Post models, add them to ObservableCollection, which then fires OnCollectionChanged which fires insert. Then I would add Gender model and then Person model. So first all the OnCollectionChanged events of ObservableCollection<Post> would get fired, then OnCollectionChanged events of ObservableCollection<Gender> and then OnCollectionChanged events of ObservableCollection<Person>.

I want to move this import to background. What I am using is an asynchronous command that makes locks, sets BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization and runs Task.Run. Inside the task I call one method that reads the file and returns data in an object and a second void method which inserts data in the ObservableCollections using lock.

The problem I have is that after the thread finishes the main thread fires the OnCollectionChanged events alternately:

- One Post model is added -> fires OnCollectionChanged
- One Gender model is added -> fires OnCollectionChanged
- One Person is added -> fires OnCollectionChanged
- One Post model is added
- One Gender model is added
- One Person is added
- etc...

This causes errors as it tries to insert Person model whose Gender model and Post model have not yet been inserted. Is this expected behaviour? Can I change the order of these events firing?

Comment: I think it is bad designed ... you are mixing DTO with bussines objects ... `Post`  should have field `Person` and `Person`  should have field `Gender` then there would be no problem ... more over you may use `Guid` s as ids so you could choose them before DB insertion

Comment: I do give ids before insertion. The error is thrown on insert in database as the tables include relations and it tries to insert relation to a record that does not yet exist. Person has to have relation to Post because it refers to the adress of each Person.

Comment: In my opinion, the deeper reason for your problem is the confusion of the separation of functionality between the ViewModel and the Model.
Changing real data is a function of the Model.
The observable collection in the ViewModel is only a reflection of real data.
The "Add Post" event occurs in the Model.
On this event, you must send a DTO instance with all data to the ViewModel.
But unless you have a Person to fill in all the links in the Post, you cannot form the DTO Post.

Comment: Therefore, in the Model, you first form a DTO Person, create an event with this DTO.
On this event, the VM adds it to its collection, and the collection update is also marshaled to the UI thread there.
Then the Model creates an instance of the DTO Post, an event for it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding all at the same time, you can put the adding into one task or have the tasks start in order.

```
Task.Run(() => 
{
    AddPosts();
    AddGenders();
    AddPersons();
}
```

This way it is asynchronous but in the correct order.

Comment: This implementation does not guarantee the correct sequence of work.
You're leaving out the fact that when an observable collection changes asynchronously, the CollectionChanged event must be marshalled to the main UI thread.
This marshaling happens asynchronously.
And there is no guarantee that marshaling the first event will be faster than marshaling the next event.